# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\overline{x}_n)^4 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^4$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, summation

I'm trying to prove the following inequality:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\overline{x}_n)^4 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^4$

where $\overline{x}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$.

This is my attempt: we can easily show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\overline{x}_n)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$, then

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\overline{x}_n)^4 \leq \bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x}_n)^2\bigg]^2\leq n^2 \bigg[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\bigg]^2$

Then, by using Jensen inequality, we find that

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\overline{x}_n)^4 \leq n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^4$.

The problem is that I can't find a way to get rid of the $n$ factor.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

A proof for non-negative variables.

Since our inequality is homogeneous and even degree and for $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=0$ it's obvious, we can assume that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k=n$ and
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^4-\left(x_k-\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}\right)^4\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^4-(x_k-1)^4-4(x_k-1)\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n(4x_k^3-6x_k^2+3)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2(x_k-1)^2(2x_k+1)+1\right)\geq0.$$

Also, we need to prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nf(k_k)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=x^4-(x-1)^4$$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k=n$.

But, $$f''(x)=12x^2-12(x-1)^2=12(2x-1),$$ which says that $f$ has an unique inflection point.

Thus, by the Vasc's HCF Theorem it's enough to prove your inequality for equality case of $n-1$ variables.

I hope, all these can help you.

I got that for $n=3$ your inequality is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $n=3$ and $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (-5, -1, 5)$.

Then $x_1^4 + x_2^4 + x_3^4 = 1251$; however, $\overline{x}_3 = -\frac13$, and $(x_1 + \frac13)^3 + (x_2 + \frac13)^4 + (x_3 + \frac13)^4 = \frac{11552}{9} > 1283$.

Comment: I wonder is something can be said about where $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-x)^4$ is minimal.

Comment: It's a convex function with a critical point at the solution to $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x)^3 = 0$, which is not a particularly nice cubic equation. We can rewrite it as $x^3 - 3\mu_1 x^2 + 3\mu_2 x - \mu_3 = 0$, where $\mu_k$ is the average of the $k^{\text{th}}$ powers of $x_1, \dots, x_n$.